# Can I extend the integration to whole real line?

Tags: analysis

Let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ and set $M_x^y:=(\lvert y-x\rvert)/2$ as well as $M_y^z:=(\lvert z-y\rvert)/2$.

Is it then true that
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}f(w)\, dw = \lim_{\lvert y-x\rvert\to\infty\atop,\lvert z-y\rvert\to\infty}\int_{y-M_x^y}^{y+M_y^z}f(w)\, dw?
$$

I am asking because I need to integrate $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and on $(y-M_x^y,y+M_y^z)$ the function $f$ has nice properties which I would like to use for the integration over  whole $\mathbb{R}$ (and in my task it is supposed that both $\lvert y-x\rvert\to\infty$ and $\lvert z-y\rvert\to\infty$).

Comment: You should really define what $y-x \to \infty, z-y \to \infty$ means.

Comment: I mean the distances. I added it.

Comment: Even then you have a double limit. Two variables go to infinity. How do you define that?

Comment: I am not sure how to describe it. Maybe it is better to describe it by sequences. The point I am aiming at is that I have $x_n\leqslant y_n\leqslant z_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and then both $\lvert x_n-y_n\rvert$ and $\lvert y_n-z_n\rvert$  go to infinity. I think my question then  boils down to the question whether then $(y_n-\frac{\lvert y_n-x_n\rvert}{2},y_n+\frac{\lvert y_n-z_n\rvert}{2})\to (-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: All of this is apparently an attempt to solve another specific problem that you have in mind. Why not ask about that problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not true. If $x_n=n,y_n=2n$ then $y_n-\frac {|y_n-x_n|}  2 \to \infty$ though $|x_n-y_n| \to \infty$.

Comment: But does this example satisfy $x_n\leq y_n$?

Comment: Since indeed $0 \leq n,$ this answer was a good counterexample before the edit as well as after.

Comment: @DavidK I just edited the answer to make sure that $x_n \to \infty$. I just thought OP might add that condition after seeing my answer.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with OP adding the condition $x_n\to-\infty$, though you could easily compensate for that. (In fact $x = -n,$ $y=2n$ also is a counterexample.)

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the comment. I any case it is very unreasonable to think that $y_n-\frac {|y_n-x_n|} 2 \to -\infty$

Answer (score 0):

> $\newcommand{d}{\,\mathrm d}$... I have $x_n\leqslant y_n\leqslant z_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and then both $\lvert x_n − y_n\rvert$ and $\lvert y_n − z_n\rvert$ go to infinity.

I'll treat this as if it were part of the original question, which it apparently should have been.

The condition $x_n \leq y_n \leq z_n$ implies the following facts:
\begin{gather}
\lvert x_n − y_n\rvert = \lvert y_n − x_n\rvert = y_n − x_n, \\
\lvert y_n − z_n\rvert = \lvert z_n − y_n\rvert = z_n − y_n, \\
y_n - \frac{\lvert y_n-x_n\rvert}{2} = \frac{x_n + y_n}{2},\\
y_n + \frac{\lvert y_n-z_n\rvert}{2} = \frac{y_n + z_n}{2}.
\end{gather}

We can then simplify your right-hand integral to

$$
 \lim_{\substack{y-x\to\infty\\ z-y\to\infty}} \int_{(x + y)/2}^{(y + z)/2} f(w)\d w.
$$

Looking just at the lower bound for the moment, the fact that $y - x \to\infty$ does not tell us whether $x$ is increasing or decreasing. It might be that $x$ is increasing but $y$ is increasing faster, in which case
$\frac{x + y}{2} \to \infty,$ which is the opposite of what you want.
Likewise, $z - y \to\infty$ does not tell us whether $z$ is increasing or decreasing.
It might be that $z$ is decreasing but $y$ is decreasing faster, in which case
$\frac{y + z}{2} \to -\infty,$ again opposite to what you want.

One thing we can guarantee based on the given information is that you will not find **both** that $\frac{x + y}{2} \to \infty$
and $\frac{y + z}{2} \to -\infty.$
I suppose that at least is a good thing. But it's not much.